# Use the LAN connection of another computer in the network

Tags: windows-7, networking

I got two computers in a network, both connected through wired connections. The first one can access the internet without any restrictions. The second one can only access computers in the local network, the first one for example. I want the second computer to be able to use the first computer's internet connection, is this possible in any way?

Both computers are running Windows 7 x64 and I'm able to install any software needed on them.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

**You can use Internet Connection Sharing**

There is lots of information on the internet for how this can be done.

The first part involves disabling DHCP on your network. I'm not going to tell you how to do that because the method for doing this is specific to your setup.

For the second part, simply follow this [tutorial](http://www.home-network-help.com/windows-7-internet-connection-sharing.html). You can skip step 6 and all steps starting from step 7 contain nothing but information. You only need to perform part 2 on the computer that connects to the internet.

Note: After Internet Connection Sharing is enabled, computer one must remain on as in turned on with Windows loaded. If computer one isn't turned on then the network will not work. If you need to have a working network while computer one is turned off then the alternative is to re-enable DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for: [Share an Internet Connection Between Wireless Machines with an Ad Hoc Network in Windows 7](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21943/share-an-internet-connection-between-wireless-machines-with-an-ad-hoc-network-in-windows-7/)

This basically explains what Ad Hoc networks are and how to make one. It basically allows a computer (Computer 1) to provide an internet connection to another (Computer 2). It only requires you to have access to a wireless network and access to the control panel on computer 1. After that, PCs within a radius of 30 feet can join the new network.

Edit: If you have a wired connection: http://www.howtogeek.com/213638/how-to-share-a-wired-ethernet-internet-connection-with-all-your-devices/

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that both computers are connected by LAN.

Comment: @aequabit I've edited to use wired connections.